# Joint density function of $X$,$Y$,$Z$, independent random variables with exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, density-function

Let $X$,$Y$,$Z$ be independent random variables with exponential distribution of parameter $\lambda$, then $X,Y,Z$ ~ $\xi(\lambda)$.

Is it true that $f_{X, Y, Z}(x,y,z)=\lambda^{3}e^{-\lambda (x+y+z)}1_{[0,+\infty) \times [0,+\infty) \times [0,+\infty)}(x,y,z)$ ?

where$f_{X, Y, Z}$ is the joint density of $X,Y,Z$ and $f_{X},f_{Y},f_{Z}$ the density of $X,Y$ and $Z$.

Edit: If it's true, why are they mutually independent?

Comment: That's true. I slightly modified the notation you put to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks! But why? Are they be mutually independent?

Comment: Exactly. Meanwhile, I changed "$XYZ$" to "$X, Y, Z$" to indicate its a joint density instead of the density of the product of $X, Y$ and $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

If you change $e^{-\lambda x+y+z}$ to $e^{-\lambda(x+y+z)}$, then yes, that is correct.

Why? Well, for an exponentially distributed random variable $W$, the PDF is given by
$$f_W(w)=\lambda e^{-\lambda w}1_{[0,+\infty)}(w)$$
And for three *independently* distributed RVs $X,Y,Z$, their joint density function is given by the product of their density functions:
$$f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)f_Z(z)$$
Since the PDFS of $X,Y,Z$ are all equivalent to to $f_W$, you have
$$f_{XYZ}(x,y,z)=f_W(x)f_W(y)f_W(z)$$
Which, with some substitution and algebraic simplification, is exactly what you have.